# Error in passing a list c# of object to javascript : undefined variable

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I want to do search with predictions. I send the data (a list of objects) as JSON to Javascript by AJAX.

I have this class which is the "course" name and link from the localhost:

```
 public class SearchQ
{
    string name;
    string link;


    public SearchQ(string a, string b)
    {
        this.name = a;
        this.link = b;

    }
    public SearchQ() { }
}
```

and my search function (in the controller) is:

```
public ActionResult SearchC(string keyword)
    {
        List<SearchQ> sq = new List<SearchQ>();
        var myItems = from u in cat.Courses select u;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(keyword))
        {
            myItems = myItems.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(keyword));


            foreach (var item in myItems)
            {
                string x= "/CourseProf/"+item.C_id;
                SearchQ s = new SearchQ(item.Name,x);
                sq.Add(s);


            }
            return Json(sq.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
        }
        else
            return Json(new List<string>(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```

My Javascript:

```js
var quickSearch = function () {
    var searchstring = $("#search-bar").val();
    var response;  //  @*'@(model.Url)'*@ 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: { keyword: searchstring },
        url: "/Home/SearchC",
        dataType: "json",
        success: success_func,
        error: console.log("AjaxError")
    });
    $('#output').html();
};
var success_func = function (data) {
    function strInArray(str, strArray) {
        for (var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
            var $str1 = strArray[i].name;
            var $str2 = strArray[i].link;

            if ($str1.match(str) && strArray.length < 5) {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it the value of `$str1` and `$str2` is `undefined`! How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you verified that you're not hitting your else clause in your controller?  It sounds like you're not actually returning the data you think you're returning.

Comment: You need to spy the json transmission... (F12/Network on Google Chrome). It should help you to solve the issue, and when not you can copy/paste it here.

Comment: no I see the returning list by debugging(step into ) !

Comment: I see in Network/response    [{},{}]

Comment: Please remove code unrelated to your problem. Also you seem to have some strange event handler nesting going on

Comment: Ok then it's c# which send you an array of 2 empty objects. You have to debug the c# part...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The members of the Csharp class "SearchQ" aren't public.

Comment: Because of this, those properties are unable to be serialized. That's why there are two objects (what you've found), but they're empty.